# Replace Builtin commands with Custom Commands for CMD.exe

Tags: windows, command-line

If I do a command like (on windows `cmd.exe`):

```
where dir
```

or

```
where cd
```

I get the following message:

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

This tends to mean to me that `cd` and `dir` are not actual programs, but are built in to `cmd.exe`.

Now the real question is:

Is there ant way to replace `cd` and `dir` with other programs?  If you wanted to replace say `more`, you could just put another program by that name in the system `PATH` in front of where `more` is.

But you cannot do that with `cd` and `dir`.  Am I just stuck with them?

Comment: Except for doskey you probably cannot do it normally because AFAIK the command processor checks against its hardcoded list of builtin commands before trying anything else. If you really need it, you could potentially resort to hacking hex-edit cmd.exe and replace builtin commands with glibberish, or intercept your keyboard input before cmd.exe gets it (won't work with batch files), or implementing a cmd.exe wrapper altogether. Does that count? What do you need to replace the builtins for, anyway?

Answer (score 5):

#### Is there any way to replace `cd` and `dir` with other programs?

No, but you can come close - here's how:

1. You can create a batch file called `dir.cmd`.

   ```
   @echo off
   setlocal
   echo I have replaced dir
   endlocal
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   F:\test>dir.cmd
   I have replaced dir

   F:\test>
   ```

   However you have to call it by its full name `dir.cmd` not just `dir`, unless…
2. You can use `doskey` to redefine `dir`:

   ```
   doskey dir=dir.cmd
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   F:\test>dir
   I have replaced dir

   F:\test>
   ```

Comment: I was hoping I would not have to resort to `doskey`....it has a lot of quirks

Comment: @DarthRubik Really?

Comment: Yes...a `doskey` macro cannot be used on either side of a pipe (which is annoying)....and that's just for starters

Comment: Example: `doskey d=dir   &    d > out.txt` does not create a new file called out.txt.  It prints to the console instead

Comment: ISTM that the first line of your answer should say, "No, but you can come close; here's how...".

Comment: @Scott Good point :) Answer clarified.